# HTML rowspan skipping over cells

Tags: html, html-table

Why is the following HTML code not producing the table I would expect?

Some of my cells are being skipped over. I want the following table (https://jsfiddle.net/t4q801s7/1/). The only difference being I want to use `rowspan` (e.g. Johnny and San Diego won't be repeated).

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>City</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="3">Johnny</td>
      <td>Bay Area</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>New York</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">San Diego</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Zack</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: 1) What did you expect and how does the result differ from it? 2) Why do you include (non-working) CSS and JavaScript code without saying how they relate to the issue?

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela 1) Can't be any more clear in how I phrased my question as it's fairly obvious. Please reread. 2) Edited the code so there's no "error" although it's output is exactly the same as before

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela you must not have seen the text below the HTML. I moved it to the top

Answer (score 0):

Table cells have `vertical-align:middle` by default, so if you don't want that, you will have to change that in the stylesheet.
(For some unfathomable reason, we seem to need `!important` here. Sorry.)

```css
table, td, th {
  vertical-align: baseline !important; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>City</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="3">Johnny</td>
      <td>Bay Area</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>New York</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">San Diego</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Zack</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The problem, however, as you can see, is that with a table cell with a height of three rows, it doesn't have the contiguous lines between the rows. Table cells don't have borders inside of them, and table rows can't have borders of their own! So you will have to think about a workaround for that. Again, sorry.